# How can I run Deep Dream on Android

Tags: java, android, python

How can I run Google Deep Dream on Android? Can I execute the Python script or do I need to port it to Java for performance reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no.

Google deepdream is an iPython notebook with dependencies on caffe which itself has several dependencies.

There is however no reason why someone couldn't develop a similar tool for Android. There is an app called dreamscope for producing these kinds of images that is available for android, but I would presume they do all of their image computation in the cloud.